# Webpage can be only opened in private browsing mode

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I am experiencing an interesting problem. When I try to open the page https://projecteuler.net/ in Firefox or Chrome in the normal mode, then I get back a 500 Internal Server Error. However, when I open this page in the private browsing of FF or incognito of Chrome, the the page opens without any problem.

I am wondering what could have causes this phenomena. It is not that reading or operating cookies goes wrong, since in the private mode, I can still sign in and do all user-specific stuff.

Comment: I can open that page perfectly normally in Firefox on Ubuntu. Have you tried Safe Mode? Also, try with your internet security software disabled: it may have the site on a black list for some reason.

Comment: @AFH Now it's working for me too. I think there was some temporary problems with this page. I was just wondering what it might have been.

Comment: Yes, the overlooked variant: a lesson or reminder for all of us. Not only did you test with a different software environment, you tested at a different time. I've been caught by that myself in the past, and not only in the field of computing.